# reading coordinates from text file and then implementing it on the equations

Tags: python

hi am doing a final year project on a drawing robot using raspberry pi, i have to write a code in python for inverse kinematics, the equation for the inverse kinematics is done the text file contains coordinates i want to run the coordinates from the text file in the equations and then produce the result.
this is just the sample of the the text file.
x   y   z
38  38  0
53  38  0
68  38  0
83  38  0
98  38  0
113 38  0
128 38  0
143 38  0
158 38  0
173 38  0
188 38  0
188 53  0
188 68  0
188 83  0
188 98  0
188 113 0

```
print "\nReading the entire file at once."
text_file = open("read_it.txt","r")
print text_file.read()
text_file.close()

import math 
import sys


Yo=350
Lo=16
L1=220
L2=220
L3=146


angle=180
angle2=360


x=188(these once actually should be read from the text file)
y=188(these once actually should be read from the text file)

Xe=math.sqrt(math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2))
Ye=y

sin=math.sin
cos=math.cos
from math import pi

Xp=Xe-Lo-(L3*math.cos(-90))
Yp=Ye-Yo-(L3*math.sin(-90))
b=math.sqrt(math.pow(Xp,2)+math.pow(Yp,2))

alpha=math.atan((math.sqrt(4*math.pow(L2,2)-math.pow(b,2)))/b)
gamma=math.atan((Yp/Xp))


Theta3=(alpha*angle2)/pi
Theta2=(-180/pi)*(alpha + gamma)
Theta4=-90-Theta2-Theta3

print " Theta2= ",(-180/pi)*(alpha + gamma)
print " Theta3= ",(alpha*angle2)/pi
print " Theta4= ",-90-Theta2-Theta3
```

Comment: Please edit to make your problem statement more specific. What do you want the program to do? What is it failing to do? Be more specific.

Comment: Please add a sample of the datafile as well.

Comment: the coordinates are actually in rows in the text file every coordinate is in a new line

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not "capturing the data" you are just opening the file and reading it and then close the file.

For starters, you would need to iterate through the output of the file. I should suggest you refer to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This
>   is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:

```
 for line in f:
        print line

This is the first line of the file.
Second line of the file
```

you might want to capture the data in a list as follows:

```
angles_list = []
for line in f:
    angles_list.append(line)
```

for more on data structures refer to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

this way, you will be able to access the data from the list.